# ng-if content not updating when in ng-leave phase

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if, ng-animate

If this snippet is run:

```
<div ng-init="o={i:1}" ng-click="o.i = o.i + 1">
    <h1>{{o.i}}</h1>
    <div class="test" ng-if="o.i < 3" style="transition: 3s all;">
        <h1>{{o.i}}</h1>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="o.i=0">reset</button>
</div>
```

`{{o.i}}` displays the incrementing number on each click, but once `o.i=3`, the inner h1 still displays `{{2}}` though it's not hidden for 3 more seconds.  Is it possible for that to update until the animation is complete and the item is hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `ng-if` to `ng-show`:

```html
<div ng-init="o={i:1}" ng-click="o.i = o.i + 1">
    <h1>{{o.i}}</h1>
    <div class="test" ng-show="o.i < 3" style="transition: 3s all;">
        <h1>{{o.i}}</h1>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="o.i=0">reset</button>
</div>
```